# Can't import function from tsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, import

I'm using react+typescript+webpack.

I'm trying to import the function `drawOnCanvasHelper` contained in the package `react-financial-charts`, which I've correctly npm installed. The function is exported from the file: https://github.com/reactivemarkets/react-financial-charts/blob/f5a2ab4b537652770c4ff8a1805678fb149861e9/packages/series/src/StackedBarSeries.tsx

I've tried to import it in two different ways:

```
import { drawOnCanvasHelper } from "@react-financial-charts/series";
```

```
import { drawOnCanvasHelper } from "react-financial-charts";
```

However, they both generate the same error message:

```
TS2305: Module '"react-financial-charts"' has no exported member 'drawOnCanvasHelper'.
```

```
TS2305: Module '"@react-financial-charts/series"' has no exported member 'drawOnCanvasHelper'.
```

I don't understand this error message, since the file inside that package definitely does export that function. So, how can I import this function correctly for use in my project?

Comment: `import drawOnCanvasHelper from "@react-financial-charts/series";`

use like this

Comment: @MonzoorTamal No, it's not a default export so that won't work. The answer I've accepted is the correct one - it's simply not possible to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, in the [`/packages/series/src/index.ts` file](https://github.com/reactivemarkets/react-financial-charts/blob/f5a2ab4b537652770c4ff8a1805678fb149861e9/packages/series/src/index.ts), they only export `StackedBarSeries` and `StackedBarSeriesProps` from the `StackedBarSeries` component

As per the link:

```
// index.ts
export * from "./AlternateDataSeries";
export * from "./AlternatingFillAreaSeries";
export * from "./AreaOnlySeries";
export * from "./AreaSeries";
export * from "./markers";
export * from "./LineSeries";
export * from "./CandlestickSeries";
export * from "./OHLCSeries";
export * from "./BarSeries";
export { StackedBarSeries, StackedBarSeriesProps } from "./StackedBarSeries";
export * from "./GroupedBarSeries";
export * from "./KagiSeries";
export * from "./PointAndFigureSeries";
export * from "./RenkoSeries";
export * from "./MACDSeries";
export * from "./BollingerSeries";
export * from "./RSISeries";
export * from "./StochasticSeries";
export * from "./ElderRaySeries";
export * from "./VolumeProfileSeries";
export * from "./ScatterSeries";
export * from "./StraightLine";
export * from "./SARSeries";
```

Therefore, you cannot get the `drawOnCanvasHelper` function. Though they export the function, it might only be used for internal developers - end users only get access to the `StackedBarSeries` class and `StackedBarSeriesProps` interface

Hope I am making sense